# Measuring Program Execution Time with Cycle Counters

Tags: inline-assembly, performancecounter, execution-time

I have confusion in this particular line-->

```
result = (double) hi * (1 << 30) * 4 + lo;
```

of the following code:

```
void access_counter(unsigned *hi, unsigned *lo)
// Set *hi and *lo to the high and low order bits of the cycle
// counter. 
{
  asm("rdtscp; movl %%edx,%0; movl %%eax,%1"  // Read cycle counter
      : "=r" (*hi), "=r" (*lo)                // and move results to
      : /* No input */                        // the two outputs
      : "%edx", "%eax");
}

double get_counter()
// Return the number of cycles since the last call to start_counter.
{
    unsigned ncyc_hi, ncyc_lo;
    unsigned hi, lo, borrow;
    double result;

    /* Get cycle counter */
    access_counter(&ncyc_hi, &ncyc_lo);
    lo = ncyc_lo - cyc_lo;
    borrow = lo > ncyc_lo;
    hi = ncyc_hi - cyc_hi - borrow;
    result = (double) hi * (1 << 30) * 4 + lo;
    if (result < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: counter returns neg value: %.0f\n", result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The thing I cannot understand is that why is hi being multiplied with 2^30 and then 4? and then low added to it? Someone please explain what is happening in this line of code. I do know that what hi and low contain.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for rdtscp?  It returns a 64bit number.  The lower 32 bits in eax, and the higher 32bits in edx.  In a sensible implementation, access_counter would return a 64 bit integer.  Why this is being turned into a floating point I can't imagine.

Comment: And while I'm at it, that asm is incorrectly written. 1) It modifies ecx without informing the compiler via output or clobber (very bad). 2) It has 2 unnecessary mov statements (wasting both time and precious registers).  How about `unsigned int a; unsigned long long b =  __builtin_ia32_rdtscp(&a);`?  If you used a 64bit number for (the apparently undefined?) cyc_lo & cyc_hi, it makes subtracting newtime - oldtime easier as well.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer:**

That line turns a 64bit integer that is stored as 2 32bit values into a floating point number.

Why doesn't the code just use a 64bit integer?  Well, gcc has supported 64bit numbers for a long time, but presumably this code predates that.  In that case, the only way to support numbers that big is to put them into a floating point number.

**The long answer:**

First, you need to understand how rdtscp works.  When this assembler instruction is invoked, it does 2 things:

1) Sets ecx to IA32_TSC_AUX MSR.  In my experience, this generally just means ecx gets set to zero.
2) Sets edx:eax to the current value of the processor’s time-stamp counter.  This means that the lower 64bits of the counter go into eax, and the upper 32bits are in edx.

With that in mind, let's look at the code.  When called from get_counter, access_counter is going to put edx in 'ncyc_hi' and eax in 'ncyc_lo.'  Then get_counter is going to do:

```
lo = ncyc_lo - cyc_lo;
borrow = lo > ncyc_lo;
hi = ncyc_hi - cyc_hi - borrow;
```

What does this do?

Since the time is stored in 2 different 32bit numbers, if we want to find out how much time has elapsed, we need to do a bit of work to find the difference between the old time and the new.  When it is done, the result is stored (again, using 2 32bit numbers) in hi / lo.

Which finally brings us to your question.

```
result = (double) hi * (1 << 30) * 4 + lo;
```

If we could use 64bit integers, converting 2 32bit values to a single 64bit value would look like this:

```
unsigned long long result = hi; // put hi into the 64bit number.
result <<= 32;                  // shift the 32 bits to the upper part of the number
results |= low;                 // add in the lower 32bits.
```

If you aren't used to bit shifting, maybe looking at it like this will help.  If lo = 1 and high = 2, then expressed as hex numbers:

```
result = hi;   0x0000000000000002
result <<= 32; 0x0000000200000000
result |= low; 0x0000000200000001
```

But if we assume the compiler doesn't support 64bit integers, that won't work.  While floating point numbers can hold values that big, they don't support shifting.  So we need to figure out a way to shift 'hi' left by 32bits, *without* using left shift.

Ok then, shifting left by 1 is really the same as multiplying by 2.  Shifting left by 2 is the same as multiplying by 4.  Shifting left by [omitted...] Shifting left by 32 is the same as multiplying by 4,294,967,296.

By an amazing coincidence, 4,294,967,296 == (1 << 30) * 4.

So why write it in that complicated fashion?  Well, 4,294,967,296 is a pretty big number.  In fact, it's too big to fit in an 32bit integer.  Which means if we put it in our source code, a compiler that doesn't support 64bit integers may have trouble figuring out how to process it.  Written like this, the compiler can generate whatever floating point instructions it might need to work on that really big number.

**Why the current code is wrong:**

It looks like variations of this code have been wandering around the internet for a long time.  Originally (I assume) access_counter was written using rdtsc instead of rdtscp.  I'm not going to try to describe the difference between the two (google them), other than to point out that rdtsc does not set ecx, and rdtscp does.  Whoever changed rdtsc to rdtscp apparently didn't know that, and failed to adjust the inline assembler stuff to reflect it.  While your code might work fine despite this, it might do something weird instead.  To fix it, you could do:

```
asm("rdtscp; movl %%edx,%0; movl %%eax,%1"  // Read cycle counter
  : "=r" (*hi), "=r" (*lo)                  // and move results to
  : /* No input */                          // the two outputs
  : "%edx", "%eax", "%ecx");
```

While this will work, it isn't optimal.  Registers are a valuable and scarce resource on i386.  This tiny fragment uses 5 of them.  With a slight modification:

```
asm("rdtscp"  // Read cycle counter
  : "=d" (*hi), "=a" (*lo)
  : /* No input */
  : "%ecx");
```

Now we have 2 fewer assembly statements, and we only use 3 registers.

But even that isn't the best we can do.  In the (presumably long) time since this code was written, gcc has added both support for 64bit integers and a function to read the tsc, so you don't need to use asm at all:

```
unsigned int a;
unsigned long long result;

result =  __builtin_ia32_rdtscp(&a);
```

'a' is the (useless?) value that was being returned in ecx.  The function call requires it, but we can just ignore the returned value.

So, instead of doing something like this (which I assume your existing code does):

```
unsigned cyc_hi, cyc_lo;

access_counter(&cyc_hi, &cyc_lo);
// do something
double elapsed_time = get_counter(); // Find the difference between cyc_hi, cyc_lo and the current time
```

We can do:

```
unsigned int a;
unsigned long long before, after;

before =  __builtin_ia32_rdtscp(&a);
// do something
after =  __builtin_ia32_rdtscp(&a);
unsigned long long elapsed_time = after - before;
```

This is shorter, doesn't use hard-to-understand assembler, is easier to read, maintain and produces the best possible code.

But it does require a relatively recent version of gcc.